# How to chain getElementById and getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a div with id "productPriceContainer" and within this div a class "price". 
I want to access the innerHTML of class "price" since I have other classes called "price" as well.

Can I chain something like this?

```
document.getElementById(productPriceContainer).getElementsByClassName(price).innerHTML
```

If not what is the correct way of doing what I need?

Thanks

Comment: There is no function getElementByClassName.

Comment: @dystroy - [?](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Notice the **s** ? It's very important. It explains why you can't chain just like that.

Comment: @dystroy - a more helpful (first) comment would have pointed that out, if that's all you wished to highlight there.

Comment: haha sorry guys, modified that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have one element with class `price` in the element with id `productPriceContainer`, you can do

```
 document.getElementById('productPriceContainer')
     .getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerHTML
```

Notice the **s** in `getElementsByClassName`. It explains why you can't chain just like that. You don't have a function called `getElementByClassName` because, contrary to the id, there is no unicity of elements having a given class.

Comment: There is also the choice of using querySelector, which is much more succinct.

Comment: @nhahtdh Right. But [less compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector).

Comment: for some reason I get "undefined" in my variable when I attempt to retrieve the innerHTML, what could be reason for this?

Comment: @user208709 Could you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the HTML ? Are you sure you've put the `[0]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Almost.

- If you want to pass strings, then you have to pass strings and not undefined variables
- `getElementsByClassName` (plural!) returns a NodeList, not a Node, so you have to loop over it to get the Nodes (on which you can then use `innerHTML`.

Comment: for some reason I get "undefined" in my variable when I attempt to retrieve the innerHTML, what could be reason for this?

Comment: @user208709 — That you are still trying to access the `innerHTML` of the NodeList instead of looping over it and accessing the `innerHTML` of one or more of the elements inside it.

Comment: so you mean I have to assign [0] if I want to access the innerHTML of the first child in the NodeList right?

Answer (score 1):

1. You are passing a variable, not a String to the method -> it should be `"price"` not `price`.
2. The Method for retrieving Nodes by a classname is `getElementsByClassName` *you were missing the "s"*
3. It returns an Array of DOM Elements so you have to iterate over the childs of your container

For example:

`document.getElementById("productPriceContainer").getElementsByClassName("price")[0].innerHTML = "Asdf";`

sets the `innerHTML` of the first DOM element with the class `"price"` within your container Element to "Asdf"

Iterating over the Elements could look like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementById("productPriceContainer")
if(elements) {
  var classes = elements.getElementsByClassName("price");
   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     elements[i].innerHTML = "Asdf" + i;
    }
}
```

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/avomuh/1/edit)

Comment: Thats right, but if you iterate over the Elements and the Nodelist's length is 0 it won't start the loop. -> I'll add an example with a simple for loop

Comment: That doesn't correct the error if there is no element with id `productPriceContainer`.  Many other answers to this question have the same problem.  Your's was the first one I saw.